# Maven can't download dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, repository

i have a big problem since this morning. prefix that i already checked if this problem was solved but , tought ther are simylar problem, my error persist.

the problem is that when i'm trying to add a new dependency in the project pom ,maven can't download and says "could't solve artifact .." , in the m2 repository, for example imagine that i'm trying to add postgresql dependency, in the postgresql folder there are only lastUpdated file . i know it means that maven create this file because it can't download it and they "remember" that but, why?? i tryed everything from other similar post, like build clean install -U , or deletting from cmd all .lastUpdated file or cleaning the workspace and create a new one but unsolved my problem. the funny thing is that when i change the project in another eclipse workspace (and the settings associated to them) it goes. my friend have the same configuration (settings ecc) of the project and he doesn't have this problem, so i think isn't a problem of settings.

have you got some advice for me? i not posting any code but if you need something i will do.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem sometimes, especially in the work network.

I have 2 variants which help me to solve that problem:

1)Just go with your Terminal into the directory and run "mvn compile". Then it should work.
If not you can try to Invalidate the Caches and Restart IntelliJ:
File->Invalidate Caches & Restart"

2)If you also use Idea, you can change maven version from its on yours. In my case, I changed from maven3 to maven, which I have on C:\maven. After that, all dependencies would be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

This case had troubled me for a while, just add a repository in your project pom.xml. And this can solve my problen bellow, have a try and good luck~

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-release</id>
            <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>oss-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alimaven</id>
            <name>aliyun maven</name>
            <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to explain your reply a little bit, not just bringing it. In your case, there are additional answer, so expose the Cons and Pros of your P.O.V.

Answer (score -1):

Maven is more of a convenience that saves you from needing to go out to the world wide net, and manually download all the jar files. It isn't always perfect.

I recommend that you manually look up and download the jar file you need on the interweb.

Then, use this format at the command line to manually add it to your Maven repository:

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.example -DartifactId=example -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jta-1.0.1.jar
>   (above was just an example and you will need to look up the specifics for your jar file. )

Comment: *Maven is more of a convenience that saves you from needing to go out to the world wide net* - This is totally not true, from where do you think Maven downloads tons of jars and dependencies? From repositories like [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/), [Mvn Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) and a lot of other mirrors

Comment: I meant  that it was created to centralize the jars instead of needing to download them from different sources.